# Term for someone who has been 'liked' on social media

Tags: single-word-requests

In our system we have the ability to 'like' someone. Similar to how you like someone on social media websites.

Is there a term for someone who has been liked? As in a 'Likee'? Similar to how you have a 'Payee' and a 'Payer'.

Comment: A person can be the **recipient** of likes.

Comment: Sounds like a 'Likee' to me ... or should that be 'Lickee'? ,,, hm, maybe that depends on how Hot there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a question of naming something in software, I would use “liked” as a noun (“[the] liked”), or an adjective (“liked person”) especially if there are other things that can be “liked” (pages, posts, comments, &c.). In speech or a user interface, that might come across as rather formal, though, like “the accused” or “the deceased”, so there I might phrase it differently—e.g., “people you’ve liked”.

Answer (score 0):

He is a most popular "Cyberstar".

She is an "Internet celebrity".

These words we can use in the context.

Answer (score -1):

If the liking is reciprocal, you could call them a [friend](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/friend).

In the [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/) system, people you like are your *friends*, people who like you are your *fans*. People you dislike are your *foes*, and people who dislike you are your *freaks*, which is a bit weak and presumably only chosen for alliterative reasons.